# Set a variable to the data element

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables

Setting up a Flickr script... In my ajax success function, how would I put a var in with the actual **this** element? I know **this** and **$(this)** represent different things. Hard to write out, so I'll use my code examples to explain better.

I have my function set with the defined variables: `function flickr_feed(flickrID, flickr_count, photo_size) {`, which the variable in question is the `photo_size`

Using a condition to set the `getSize` variable from the readable format in `photo_size`:

`if (photo_size == 'square') var getSize = 'url_sq';`

I then dump that `getSize` into the ajax url:

```
url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=' + flickrAPI + '&user_id=' + flickrID + '&per_page=' + flickr_count + '&page=0&extras=' + getSize + '&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
```

The problem I'm having in the success function is setting that `getSize` var to the element.

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.photos.photo, function() {
        var photoID = 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/' + flickrID + '/' + this.id;
        var photoSrc = this.getSize;
        console.log(photoSrc);
    });
}
```

In this result, `photoSrc` returns undefined. But if I manually set `photoSrc` to `this.url_sq`, it's fine. Just can't figure out how to get the variable in there to work the same way.

Apologies for the horrible explanation. If it makes sense at all, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** My experience with $.ajax is limited. But from what I gather, **this** refers to the returned data. So in that sense, the `photoSrc` returns undefined as it is thinking `getSize` is a result within the data, which it isn't. So how would that be written so that it would use the actual `getSize` value?

**EDIT:** Here's a pastebin of the script:  http://pastebin.com/KGCUgAet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it out with writing the `photoSrc` var like this:  `var photoSrc = this[getSize];`

Thanks Sushanth for confirming my question about **this** and the returned data. That helped figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Cache your this before your **ajaxRequest**

```
var originalContext = this;
$.ajax({


success: function() {
     $.each(data.photos.photo, function() {

          originalContext // Available here
          this  // Current object under iteration
     });
}
```

Comment: Nothing doing there. Still returns undefined.

Comment: I'm still not familiar enough with ajax. But it looks like **this** applies to the returned data in the $.each. So the context is within the $.each, right?

Comment: I added a pastebin link to the full script, if that helps at all.